# rmmod when char dev is open

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel

I tried to remove a kernel module using rmmod when a device is open in a file descriptor (another C++ program). When I closed the C++ program I have this:

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 7f023588
pgd = 80004000
[7f023588] *pgd=388aa811, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 7 [#2] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: [last unloaded: dev]
CPU: 2 PID: 1272 Comm: helloWorld Tainted: P      D W  O    4.1.38-fslc+gee67fc7 #4
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
task: a8c42d00 ti: a89f8000 task.ti: a89f8000
PC is at filp_close+0x2c/0x8c
LR is at put_files_struct+0xb4/0x10c
pc : [<8013266c>]    lr : [<80150f28>]    psr: 20070113
sp : a89f9dc0  ip : a89f9de0  fp : a89f9ddc
r10: a89f9edc  r9 : a8ada8c0  r8 : 00000000
r7 : a89f4d00  r6 : a89f4d00  r5 : a8832f00  r4 : 00000001
r3 : 7f023554  r2 : a8832f00  r1 : a89f4d00  r0 : a8832f00
Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 38a0404a  DAC: 00000015
Process helloWorld (pid: 1272, stack limit = 0xa89f8210)
Stack: (0xa89f9dc0 to 0xa89fa000)
```

Is it possible to resolve this problem? How?

Comment: Did you call `try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);` and `module_put(THIS_MODULE);` in the open/close-functions?

Comment: Show the **code** of your kernel module (in form of [mcve]).

Comment: @Ctx Thanks. This is it. So far I have not found out about try_module_get/module_put.

Comment: Congrats! You found a lazy developer who had not thought about object lifetime. Perhaps it's you who did that.

Answer (score 3):

Proper way for **prevent** kernel module from unload while file is opened is to set `.owner` field of `file_operations` structure:

```
static struct file_operations my_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    //...
};
```

---

**NOTE**: Manual using of `try_module_get(THIS_MODULE)` and `module_put(THIS_MODULE)` is subject to **race conditions**, when module is unloaded immediately before `try_module_get()` call, so futher code could be unmapped.

Comment: It will not help against unbinding.

Comment: @0andriy: What do you mean by "unbinding"?

Comment: I meant *unbinding*. https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/ (Even after your change code is **still** buggy)

Comment: If I undestand this article correctly, **by default** driver simply cannot be unbinding, so there is no problem here. Writing "unbindable" driver is another question.

Comment: Why not? Nothing prevents you to remove device structures while Linux device node is being opened. You missed the concept.

Comment: Hm, another point of view: unbinding is supported only for **physical devices**, which are connected to a bus or whatever. And the question is about *character device* (see the title), which is rarely physical (and there is no actual *driver*, which can be connected to the device). For such kernel modules setting `.owner` field works perfectly.

Comment: Can you point me to a real use case when character device doesn't belong to any real device in Linux kernel? (Yes, I know that the example above is just an educational case) For me it looks like you still try to desperately find an argument that your answer is fully correct when it actually isn't.

Comment: `allocate_chardev_region`, `cdev_add`, `device_create` - they creates pure virtual device, which has no underline physical things. Can one unbind such device? I think not.

Comment: I'm not opposing that. What I'm telling is that there would be only few specific examples where it would be done like that, in ultimate majority of the cases there will be an underlying real device.

Comment: `there would be only few specific examples where it would be done like that` - There is a lot of **real** examples, where "virtual" character device (or its debugfs or sysfs analogue) is sufficient, e.g. debugging tools like that https://github.com/euspectre/kedr (I was involved). `For me it looks like you still try to desperately find an argument that your answer is fully correct when it actually isn't.` - For me it looks like you want to **mix every problem** about Linux kernel development into single one. This question(and my answer) are specific for protection against **module unloading**.

Comment: Maybe I'm right, maybe I'm wrong, though I don't believe in blind guesses (which I also make from time to time), put the numbers on the table. And problem is beyond the educational example. On this I have stopped the pointless discussion.

Comment: @Tsyvarev No, it is no problem to use `try_module_get()` and `module_put()` race-free. Why should it be? For further reference see https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/module-init-tools/FAQ

Comment: @Ctx: Imaging that `rmmod` is called *after* `.open` function begins and *before* `try_module_get()`. In that case pages with your module's code will be simple unloaded, and you will get Oops when `.open` function continues. Exactly that is written in my answer post.